# How to make http client for GWT-RPC service

Tags: gwt, httpclient, gwt-rpc

I want to make client for GWT service, which does **not** belong to me.  Service uses RPC. I would like to use apache httpclient but there is problem with strong hash name, which are changed sometimes and messages contains a lot of values which are not understandable for human. I know that java scripts generate this message. 
By now I watch every request by Firebug and I copy content of request to my client app and I change a few vaules which I need from a lot of values which are included in message. This takes time and sometimes a strong hash names are changed so I have to change my client code. 
Is there any better solution? I think that the best solution is to execute javascript and generate right message, but I have no idea how to do that and I am afraid that this add complexity to my app.

I have a very little knowledge about GWT.

Comment: The solution is to ask the maintainer of the service to provide a "Web API" for it. Everything else will be hackish and non-future-proof workarounds. GWT-RPC is only meant to be used by a Web app served by the same server(s), not the way you're trying to use it.